# Character on hanging list

Tags: line-breaking

I'm the maintainer of the `ledmac` package (for critical editions).

I would like to have the possibility to start all the lines with hanging indentation with some chosen character, like this (where this character would be `[`):

```
A very long, very long, very long,very long,
   [very long, very long, very long line
   [A hanged line
   [Another hanged line
A very long, very long, very long,very long,
   [very long, very long,very long line
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make a [character]"? Would you be able to provide a visual of what you're after?

Comment: Welcome Maieul! Nice to see you here! Since you're here now, I added your profile to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here :-)

Comment: Welcone Maieul! I too am a bit confused -- are you looking to start some lines with a raised or dropped enlarged letter?

Comment: thank everybody ! I would like that some lines, whose are hanged, start with a caractère, like [. See an exemple of what I would like : http://partage.maieul.net/hanged.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something similar in the `gmdoc-enhance` package to have leading `%` signs on each comment line. It makes the space character active and expand in principle to `\discretionary{}{\gmde@kommentarStart}{}~`, where `\gmde@kommentarStart`  puts a \hbox with the contents I want to show.

The problem here is that `\gmde@kommentarStart` will be evaluated for every space, not only for those that create a line break - but only for those the box will actually occur in the output. And also, I have to make sure that no other line breaks occur, which destroys most of TeX's line breaking algorithm (i.e. I essentially need `\raggedright` and no word-breaking). This is acceptable for my use case, but might not be for your one.

Answer (score 0):

So, I find an other solution to integrate it on the ledmac / ledpar package. As the package use hbox, a made a code we everyhbox and some counters.

Comment: Would you like to expand a bit your answer telling also the general scheme of the solution?

Comment: that was not a good solution. I use an other mechanism more deeply in the eledmac package. I think we could delete this question and answer.